# calabash-android: INJECT_EVENTS permission (RuntimeError) when executing press_back_button

Tags: android, automated-tests, functional-testing, calabash-android

```
Action 'press_key' unsuccessful: java.lang.SecurityException:
Injecting to another application requires INJECT_EVENTS permission (RuntimeError)
```

That is the error I receive when Calabash encounters the `press_back_button` command in a step definition. It works perfectly fine when executed through the console **but** generates that error in the test.

Can anyone help?

---

OS: OS X 10.10

Device: Genymotion v2.3.1 Android v4.4 emulation

calabash-android v0.5.5

---

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had a similar problem. I don't know if this could solve yours:

I wanted to touch a button but got the same exception as you. It worked perfectly in the console.

I then realized that my test was entering text into a text field and the button was obstructed by the virtual keyboard. I was still able to query the button state but when I wanted to press it, i got the exception, probably because it tries from another application (the virtual keyboard) to interact with the button of my app.

Before pressing the button I had to execute `hide_soft_keyboard`

In your case, probably something else is obstructing or blocking your app. You could also make a `sleep 2` to wait for other operations to complete and then pressing the button.

Comment: Quite right. 

There was indeed an obstruction. A previous step was failing causing the app to quit two seconds later. This two-second delay gave me the impression that it was the `press_back_button` that was the cause.